# Why GregorianCalendar method add() does not work?

Tags: java, datetime, gregorian-calendar

I created a class which represent a possible user for a library system. At the moment of the creation of this instance i need to set two fields: `signingUpDate` and `expirationDate`, both are Gregorian Calendar.

`signingUpDate` is the date at the moment of the creation, and `expirationDate` is `signingUpDate` + 5 years.

```
public class User {

    private GregorianCalendar signingUpDate;
    private GregorianCalendar expirationDate;

    public User(){
        setSigningUpDate;
        setExpirationDate;
    }

    private void setExpirationDate() {
        this.expirationDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        expirationDate.add(GregorianCalendar.YEAR, 5);
    }

    private void setSigningUpDate() {
        this.signingUpDate=new GregorianCalendar();
    }
```

When I use the method `add()`, `expirationDate` doesn't change. I tried to debug and I noticed that the field `areFieldsSet` turns false. But I didn't understand the meaning of that field.
Can someone help me?

Comment: You don't appear to be actually _calling_ your methods in your constructor. I doubt this is code you are actually running. Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: Good old, no, bad old `GregorianCalendar`. Best you can do is to use `LocalDate`or another class from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It supplanted `GregorianCalendar` and the other old date and time classes nearly 5 years ago.

Comment: What is `GregorianCalendar.years`? Did you mean `Calendar.YEAR`? Anyway, I agree with @OleV.V. that this is very old. If possible, change to `java.time`

Comment: It would help us help you if you would post code that can compile and run and show the unwanted behaviour. It’s like we’re using our energy pointing out typos without knowing whether or not they have anything to do with the real cause of your problem (my guess is they haven’t).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that’s nice. I still get `setSigningUpDate cannot be resolved to a type` because of the syntax error in what should have been a method call.

Comment: Sorry i was working on it... It was a large script to post and I refactored the code to try the explanations in the answers. Thank you anyway.

Comment: FYI, the terribly troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug(?) of `GregorianCalendar`, you can call `getTime` to 'refresh' it after adding 5 year:

```
signingUpDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 5);
signingUpDate.getTime();
```

Another solution, use `java.time` package instead, for exmaple, `java.time.LocalDate`.

Comment: It’s as designed and documented (though the documentation is very hard to read and understand). So if a bug, then a bug in the design (and IMHO not the only one), not in the code.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yeah. So I add `(?)` behind `bug`.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time

```
public class User {

    private static final ZoneId ZONE = ZoneId.of("America/Kentucky/Monticello");
    private static final Period VALIDITY = Period.ofYears(5);

    private LocalDate signingUpDate;
    private LocalDate expirationDate;

    public User() {
        setSigningUpDate();
        setExpirationDate();
    }

    private void setSigningUpDate() {
        this.signingUpDate = LocalDate.now(ZONE);
    }

    private void setExpirationDate() {
        this.expirationDate = signingUpDate.plus(VALIDITY);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Signed up " + signingUpDate + " expires " + expirationDate; 
    }
}
```

java.time, the modern Java date and time API, comes without the unpleasant surprises of `GregorianCalendar` and the other date and time classes from Java 1.0 and 1.1. So the good solution is to skip the old classes and use the modern ones instead.

### What went wrong in your code?

Nothing was really wrong in your code. I’m also not quite sure what confused you, but the `GregorianCalendar` class surely is confusing, so I’m also not surprised. Maybe you looked inside the `GregorianCalendar` object in your debugger and saw that the year was unchanged and `areFieldsSet` was changed to false. They tried to document this confusing behaviour, but since it is so unnatural and different from what you’d expect, the documentation is also hard to read and understand.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.